# postgresql task that I can't seem to overcome

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

```
Highschooler(ID , name , grade ); 
Friend(ID1 , ID2 ); 
Likes(ID1 , ID2 );
```

I want to know what is the average number of friends, per student?

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results, because the question is actually ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select avg(count) 
from ( 
   select count(ID2) as count 
   from Friend 
   group by ID1 
) as FriendCount;
```

I think the part that you struggled with was, inner query in `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the average number based on `id1`, then you can do:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct id1) as avg_count
from friend;
```

I'm not 100% sure this is the right solution.  You may want:

```
select count(*) / count(distinct id1) as avg_count
from (select id1, id2
      from friend
      union all
      select id2, id1
      from friend
     ) f;
```

It depends on whether the friendships are reciprocal in the data.